# How do I embed the ArcGIS Basemap Gallery widget in an icon?

Tags: javascript, arcgis

I am using the basemap gallery widget from arcgis javascript api, however, it takes up alot of my map. How do I make it into a clickable icon that shows the gallery when clicked and i can choose a basemap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try placing the basemap gallery in and *Expand*. This will allow you to toggle the gallery and expand it whenever you want to.

```
const basemapGallery = new BasemapGallery({
  view: view
});

const galleryExpand = new Expand({
  expandIconClass: "esri-icon-layer-list",  
  view: view,
  content: basemapGallery
});

view.ui.add(galleryExpand, {
  position: "top-right"
});
```

Comment: Hi thanks for responding. I copied the code you attached for the expand but it didn't work. It comes up blank. Please help if you can.

Comment: Can you append your code, so i can make it work with your setup?
You will have to add `require(["esri/widgets/Expand"], (Expand) =>` if you haven't done that already

Comment: I went ahead and did that and it now works. Thank you so much. I appreciate you answering.

Comment: Another thing, the measurement widget doesn't work for me. Could you please assist?

Comment: Sorry I have not used the measurment widget, so I am not able to help you there. If the answer fixed your problem please mark it as **accepted**